# How can I prevent non-codeowners from executing a modified GitHub Actions file

Tags: github-actions

I have an app that is deployed by a GitHub Actions workflow.

How can I ensure that anyone pushing a PR cannot just modify my GitHub Actions file, making it executable on every PR push, and circumventing the requirement of a PR review by codeowners?
I understand that I can use codeowners to control who must review a PR before it can be merged based on what code was modified, but as far as I understand now to control when a GitHub Actions file will be executed?

Comment: Who else has write access to your repo? Firstly, make sure it _doesn't matter_ if they succeed in running the deploy script on the wrong branch: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment.

Comment: Several coworkers do. Ok, I'm catching up on environments management with github actions. Unfortunately, it would appear our deployment scheme (merge master => deploy staging, release tag => deploy prod) is not (no longer?) compatible with environment management, as discussed in this thread: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/62991#discussioncomment-6690490